# update ng-repeat with filter

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have some angular code that I am working with and hopefully soon refactoring.
I am trying to filter through a `ng-repeat` based off of a checkbox.

I have a data tree that looks like so ...

```
{
    name: 'mail',
    rating: 2.4,
    source: 'EDD',
    users: 1000,
    description: ''
}
```

The `ng-repeat` work is set up to iterate through

```
<li ng-repeat="rule in property">{{rule[entityPropertyName]}</li>
```

The property was renamed off of a products service that exists in the searchController like so

**HTML**

```
<search-section productName="qualifier" 
                product="qualifiers" 
                entityPropertyName="name"></search-section>
```

**Directive**

```
controller: 'searchController',
scope: {
    product: '=',
    productName: '@',
    entityPropertyName: '@'
},
```

I am filtering through the checkbox with a simple function in the controller

```
$scope.filterAdded = function(sourceName) {
    if($scope.filteredQualifiers.sourceName[sourceName]) {
        return sourceName;
    }
}  // returns source name
```

The source name is returned  ex: **media**, or **age**.

I was hopeful that I could add

```
$scope.filterAdded
```

to the `ng-repeat` iterator like so

```
<li ng-repeat="rule in property | filter: filterAdded">{{rule[entityPropertyName]}</li>
```

This filter would be supported from the directive like so

```
scope: {
    entities: '=',
    entityName: '@',
    entityPropertyName: '@',
    filterAdded: '&'
},
```

With filterAdded being seen as a function.

With filter added returning a single value like   **EDD**

I identified that I that I would need to filter through the rule source.

```
source: 'EDD'
```

Not seeing a way that I could compare get **rule.source** and the filterAdded value.

```
<li ng-repeat="rule in property | filter: filterAdded"></li>
```

Any insight or feedback is appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I'm into Angular 4, so I will use this language but you can adapt to angular js (1.x).

If I got it right, would use the ngFor or ngRepeat with the ngIf instead of using pipes.

```
<ul *ngFor=" let rule in property">
```

*note that the ngFor would be used for the ul, not the li.

Then, on li tag I would use the ngIf to check if it is under a certain filter. On the ngIf you can bind to a function and even pass properties of the object or items of the array you are iterating like:

```
<li *ngIf="isThisOnFilter(rule['rating'])">{{ rule['name'] }}</li>
```

Hope it helps.